# std::function, Clang 6.0 & MSVC (10.0017134.12) - possible ABI bug or required compiler flags

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, abi, std-function

If I create a simple library (built using CMake):

**foo.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>

void foo(std::function<void()> handler);
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo(std::function<void()> handler)
{
    handler();
}
```

And then create a separate CMake project compiling an executable:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    foo([&]()
    {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    });

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And then compile the library using MSVC (using latest platform SDK 10.0.17134.12) in Release or RelWithDebInfo (remember I'm using CMake) and I compile the executable using Clang 6 (Clang 5 is not supported with the latest Windows Platform SDK bundled with Visual Studio 17.7 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/) also using Release or RelWithDebInfo, then I get heap corruption triggered by the `std::function` destructor.

To trigger heap corruption reliably, I can use `gflags`.

```
    gflags -p /enable "myexe.exe" /full
```

It worked fine with Clang 5 on the previous platform SDK (standard Clang available for download from LLVM, not Microsoft's version). I'm assuming this is an ABI (or similar) problem or bug. It's taken a while to distill this all down and get a minimum verifiable reproduction. Does anyone have any suggestions about where to take it from here?

Comment: Is there any standard c++ ABI? Last time I've checked there was nothing standard. AFAIK clang and gcc can generate compatible code, but they are often not fully backwards compatible between their own versions. Is your problem a known thing, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @luk32, clang-cl.exe is intended to be ABI compatible with msvc.exe

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be an ABI issue from what I can tell, so I reported a bug:

https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39962

**Update:**

The bug was fixed in https://reviews.llvm.org/rL328386 and is included in Clang 7.0.0.